# control stdin and stdout of a ruby program in python

Tags: python, ruby, python-2.7, python-3.x, six-python

First I should notice: I'm a python programmer with no knowledge about ruby!

Now, I need to feed stdin of a ruby program and capture stdout of the script with
a python program.
I tried [this](http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge) (forth solution) and the code works in python2.7 but not in python3; The python3 code reads input with no output.

Now, I need a way to tie the ruby program to either python 2 or 3.

### My try:

This code written with six module to have cross version compatibility.

- python code:

  ```
  from subprocess import Popen, PIPE as pipe, STDOUT as out

  import six

  print('launching slave')
  slave = Popen(['ruby', 'slave.rb'], stdin=pipe, stdout=pipe, stderr=out)

  while True:
      if six.PY3:
          from sys import stderr
          line = input('enter command: ') + '\n'
          line = line.encode('ascii')
      else:
          line = raw_input('entercommand: ') + '\n'
      slave.stdin.write(line)
      res = []
      while True:
          if slave.poll() is not None:
              print('slave rerminated')
              exit()
          line = slave.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip()
          print('line:', line)
          if line == '[exit]': break
          res.append(line)
      print('results:')
      print('\n'.join(res))
  ```
- ruby code:

  ```
  while cmd = STDIN.gets
      cmd.chop!
      if cmd == "exit"
          break
      else
          print eval(cmd), "\n"
          print "[exit]\n"
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  ```

### NOTE:

Either another way to do this stuff is welcomed! (like socket programming, etc.)
Also I think it's a better idea to not using pipe as stdout and use a file-like object. (like `tempfile` or `StringIO` or etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `bufsize`. In Python 2.x, default value was 0 (unbufffered). And in Python 3.x it changed to `-1` (using default buffer size of system).

Specifying it explicitly will solve your problem.

```
slave = Popen(['ruby', 'slave.rb'], stdin=pipe, stdout=pipe, stderr=out, bufsize=0)
```

[DEMO](http://asciinema.org/a/12517)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code on how I got it working with Ruby & Python3.

**Ruby Slave**

```
# read command from standard input:
while cmd = STDIN.gets
  # remove whitespaces:
  cmd.chop!
  # if command is "exit", terminate:
  if cmd == "exit"
    break
  else
    # else evaluate command, send result to standard output:
    print eval(cmd), "\n"
    print "[exit]\n"
    # flush stdout to avoid buffering issues:
    STDOUT.flush
  end
end
```

**Python master**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE as pipe, STDOUT as out

print('Launching slave')
slave = Popen(['ruby', 'slave.rb'], stdin=pipe, stdout=pipe, stderr=out, bufsize=0)

while True:
    from sys import stderr
    line = input('Enter command: ') + '\n'
    line = line.encode('ascii')
    slave.stdin.write(line)
    res = []
    while True:
        if slave.poll() is not None:
            print('Slave terminated')
            exit()
        line = slave.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip()
        if line == '[exit]': break
        res.append(line)
    print('results:')
    print('\n'.join(res))
```